# How to count how many times a value occurs after another

Tags: r

I'm new to R but I need to use it to find out how many times one value occurs after another. Basically, I have 5 numbers (0,1,2,3,4) listed in a random order 38 times. I need to find out how many times the value 0 occurs after 0, 1 occurs after 0, 2 after 0... so on, until I reach 4 occurs after 4. Is there any command to do this?

Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 10):

probably this command do that:

```
library(plyr) # if absent, type > install.packages('plyr')
z <- sample(0:4, 38, T) # data
count(data.frame(embed(rev(z),2))) # do it
```

Comment: you could also do `table( data.frame(...) )` to get results in matrix form. Note that the `plyr::count` will not include pairs which have zero counts.

Comment: It also doesn't include counts for the infinite number of other combinations that dont occur in the data either ;)

Comment: if you need zero count, then data.frame(table(data.frame(embed(rev(z),2)))) will do it... ugly..., and if you need the infinite number of other combinations, Haskell may do it ;)

Answer (score 10):

Create a data frame of pairs and then use `table` :

```
z <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
pairs <- data.frame(first = head(z, -1), second = tail(z, -1))
table(pairs)
```

giving:

```
     second
first 0 1 2 3 4
    0 0 2 0 0 0
    1 0 0 2 0 0
    2 0 0 0 2 0
    3 0 0 0 0 2
    4 1 0 0 0 0
```

or this which gives the original `pairs` data frame along with a `Freq` column of counts:

```
as.data.frame(table(pairs))
```